# Displaying correct value from array_values in PHP

Tags: php

I've got a simple piece of code that's returning an array here;

```
$array = ($sf_current_query->get_array());
print_r(array_values($array));
```

And it is returning this array here;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tags
            [singular_name] => Tag
            [all_items_label] => All Tags
            [type] => taxonomy
            [active_terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 100
                            [name] => Safari Tents Bell Tents and Domes
                            [value] => 01-safari-tents-bell-tents-domes
                            [count] => 231
                            )

                )

        )

)
```

What I'd like to do is return the 'name' value - "Safari Tents Bell Tents and Domes" of the first array so I've tried something like

```
    $array = ($sf_current_query->get_array());
    print_r(array_values($array[0].name));
```

But of course no joy - I've tried researching php array_values but I can't seem to get on the correct page, if anyone can point me in the correct direction of what to research that would be amazing

Comment: `array_values($array)[0]['active_terms'][0]['name']`

Comment: Yes, it's like a tree, just start at `name` and walk up.  Also, the `.` is not PHP but JS, maybe VB.